# Null Pointer Exception while unmarshalling XML with @XmlAnyElement annotation

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm currently trying to unmarshal some XML into a java object using JAXB and I'm getting a strange Null Pointer Exception. This is only an issue while unmarshalling. I can marshal with these classes just fine. Here are the relevant pieces of code (irrelevant portions are denoted by "..."):

1. The JAXB Root element:

   ```
   ...
   @XmlRootElement(name="assets")
   public class Assets {
       String product;
       Images images = new Images();

       ...

       Public Assets() {}

       ...

       public String getProduct() { return this.product; }

       @XmlAttribute(name="product")
       public void setProduct(String newProduct) { this.product = newProduct; }

       public Images getImages() { return this.images; }

       @XmlElement(name="images")
       public void setImages(Images newImages) { this.images = newImages; }

       ...
   }
   ```
2. The Images sub-element of the root element:

   ```
   ...
   @XmlRootElement(name="images")
   @XmlSeeAlso(Image.class)
   @XmlType(propOrder = {"mainAsset", "image"})
   public class Images {
       List<Image> images;
       Image mainAsset;

       private static char counter = 'a';
       private static final String prefix = "product-image-";

       // Here's the part that causes the NPE
       @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
       public List<JAXBElement<Image>> getImage() {
           final List<JAXBElement<Image>> imageList = new ArrayList<JAXBElement<Image>>();
           for (final Image g : this.images) {
               imageList.add(new JAXBElement(new QName(prefix + counter++), Image.class, g));
           }
           counter = 'a';
           return imageList;
       }

       @XmlElement(name="renditions")
       public void setImage(List<Image> newImages) { this.images = newImages; }

       public Image getMainAsset() { return this.mainAsset; }

       @XmlElement(name="main-asset-name")
       public void setMainAsset(Image newMainAsset) { this.mainAsset = newMainAsset; }
   }
   ```
3. The logic for unmarshalling the XML:

   ```
   ...
   public void modifyXML() {
   try {
       JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Assets.class, Images.class, Image.class);
       Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
       File f = new File("/path/to/my.xml");
       Assets assets = (Assets) um.unmarshal(f);
       ...
   } catch (JAXBException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   }
   ...
   ```
4. Finally, the XML I'm trying to unmarshal (it might help to know that this xml file was actually generated using the JAXB marshaller, which runs without any problems):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <assets product="TEST PRODUCT">
       <images>
           <main-asset-name>
               <path>stuff.jpg</path>
               <title>theTitle</path>
               <alt>theAlt</path>
               <description>theDescription</description>
           </main-asset-name>
           <product-image-a>
               <path>48x48.jpg</path>
               <title>theTitle</path>
               <alt>theAlt</path>
               <description>theDescription</description>
           </product-image-a>
           <product-image-b>
               <path>140x140.jpg</path>
               <title>theTitle</path>
               <alt>theAlt</path>
               <description>theDescription</description>
           </product-image-b>
           <product-image-c>
               <path>1280x1280.jpg</path>
               <title>theTitle</path>
               <alt>theAlt</path>
               <description>theDescription</description>
           </product-image-c>
           <product-image-d>
               <path>319x319.jpg</path>
               <title>theTitle</path>
               <alt>theAlt</path>
               <description>theDescription</description>
           </product-image-d>
       </images>
   </assets>
   ```

Okay, so that's all the relevant code (I think). When I run my program, I get the following error right after invoking the unmarshaller:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.my.companys.name.Images.getImage(Images.java:25)
```

And the line number referenced is the line where the for loop starts in my `Images.java` class file.

Does anyone have any ideas why `this.images` might be null here? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: I belive the issue is because there is no renditions element in the XML and hence the images is null.

Comment: That's a nice suggestion. However, even if I remove the name "renditions" from the `@XmlElement` annotation I still get the same error.

Comment: You have to map to a XML node, so that the object will get set.

Comment: Okay. You have any advice on how to do that with the XML file that I have here?

Comment: Actually all you nodes under images node are different so you will need seperate fields for each of them in the Images class like - Image product-image-a, Image product-image-b, Image product-image-c etc and add appropriate getters and setters for all the fields.

Comment: Here's the solution I came up with (it's a bit of a hack, but sometimes that's all we have to go with): First, I get the raw xml file as a string. Then, I use the built in Java find and replace to replace all the different elements under `<images>` with just `<image>`. This way, the unmarshaller does its job exactly as expected. It doesn't feel totally satisfying, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I've been using for now. It's a bit of a hack, but hell... It does the job.

First, I get the raw xml as a string instead of reading it as a file:

```
public void modifyXML() {
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Assets.class, Image.class);
        Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
        // This xml should be formatted in a way that JAXB can work with
        String rawXML = getRawXML("/path/to/my.xml");
        // Hand the modified xml to the unmarshaller
        Assets umAssets = (Assets) um.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(rawXML)));
        // Do stuff with umAssets
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String getRawXML(String path) throws IOException {
    String xml = readFile(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    // This should make it so JAXB can handle the xml properly
    xml = xml.replaceAll("<main-asset-name>", "<image>");
    xml = xml.replaceAll("</main-asset-name>", "</image>");
    xml = xml.replaceAll("<product-image.*>", "<image>");
    return xml.replaceAll("</product-image.*>", "</image>");
}

private String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) throws IOException {
    // A simple file reader
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
    return new String(encoded, encoding);
}
```

This seems to do the trick, so I'm going to use this for now. Of course, I'm still open to better solutions if anyone has one.